# Download GAE 1.4 plugin Play! framework fails Windows

Tags: playframework

When I run the command play install gae, I get this output in the console.

```
~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Will install gae-1.4
~ This module is compatible with: 1.1, and GAE 1.4.0
~ Do you want to install this version (y/n)? y
~ Installing module gae-1.4...
~
~ Fetching http://www.playframework.org/modules/gae-1.4.zip
~ [---------                 19%                          ] 103.7 KiB/s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\play\play", line 153, in <module>
    status = cmdloader.commands[play_command].execute(command=play_command, app=play_app, args=remai
ning_args, env=play_env, cmdloader=cmdloader)
  File "C:\play\framework\pym\play\commands\modulesrepo.py", line 58, in execute
    install(app, args, env)
  File "C:\play\framework\pym\play\commands\modulesrepo.py", line 378, in install
    Downloader().retrieve(fetch, archive)
  File "C:\play\framework\pym\play\commands\modulesrepo.py", line 88, in retrieve
    try: urllib.urlretrieve(url, destination, self.progress)
  File "C:\play\python\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\play\python\lib\urllib.py", line 261, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "C:\play\python\lib\socket.py", line 351, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
socket.error: [Errno 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I have tried using wget as well as simply using the browser to download however it fails partway through each time.

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this one? I had the same error while trying to run 'play eclipsfy' on my project. tia

Comment: I had the same problem... seems a download problem for file bigger than 20Mb. Someone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an incompatibility between the version you are trying to obtain and the Play version in your machine. Try specifying the latest version:

```
play install gae-1.6.0_b1
```

Although it may be GAE module doesn't work with Play 1.2.4, the documentation shows Play 1.1 in the terminal output (could be due to copy-paste on documentation)